# jQuery UI Autocomplete - ASP GridView

Tags: jquery, gridview, webforms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a inherited a Web Forms app with a Gridview on it. The grid view lists a number of auditors and costs allocated to them. In the Footer template are blank text boxes that allows the user to add a new entry to the grid. The first column features the auditor’s name, in which a jQuery UI Autocomplete is used to assist the user adding the auditor name.

The problem I’m having is that the autocomplete works perfectly for the first row added. But if the user wishes to add more than one record after the first, the autocomplete wont work.

To paint the full picture of how it all works, the autocomplete data is loaded into a hidden field

```
    private void BindAuditorAutoComplete()
    {
        var data = RetrievalProcedures.GetAuditors();
        hdAuditorData.Value = JsonObjectSerializer.ParseAuditorAutoComplete(data);
    }
```

here is the relevant column from the GridView - note the two hidden fields as well, the first being for the DB record ID (in the event of editing the record), and the second being the ID value of the selected auditor in the autocomplete.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Auditor Name">
    <HeaderStyle Width="315" />
    <ItemStyle Width="315" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblExtraAuditorName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExtraAuditorName")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblExtraAuditorName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExtraAuditorName")%>'></asp:Label>
        <uc:HiddenField2 ID="txtExtraAdditionalAuditorId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ExtraAdditionalAuditorId")%>' />
        <uc:HiddenField2 ID="txtExtraAuditorId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ExtraAuditorId")%>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <uc:HiddenField2 ID="txtExtraAdditionalAuditorId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ExtraAdditionalAuditorId")%>' />
        <uc:HiddenField2 ID="txtExtraAuditorId" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExtraAuditorName" class="dummyAuditorAutoComplete" runat="server" Style="width: 305px;"></asp:TextBox>

    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and here is the code that loads the autocomplete:

```
    function LoadAuditorExtraCostsAutoComplete() {

        $('.dummyAuditorAutoComplete').autocomplete({
            source: GetAuditorData(),
            select: function (event, ui) {
                PopulateAdditionalCostsAuditorData(ui);
                return false;
            },

            focus: function (event, ui) {
                PopulateAdditionalCostsAuditorData(ui);
                return false;
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    }
```

the GetAuditorData() simply reads the hidden field value:

```
    function GetAuditorData() {
        var auditors = eval($("#<%=hdAuditorData.ClientID%>").val());
        return auditors;
    }
```

on the select and focus event, the following function is run:

```
    function PopulateAdditionalCostsAuditorData(ui) {
        $("#cphDetails_AdditionalCostsGrid_txtExtraAuditorName").val(ui.item.Name);
        $("#cphDetails_AdditionalCostsGrid_txtExtraAuditorId").val(ui.item.Id);
    }
```

note: I am aware that I probably should be using server tags when referencing the two fields, however Visual Studio is giving me errors advising that the txtExtraAuditorName/txtExtraAuditorId doesn't exist in the current context. The issue may be related to this, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Is anyone able to assist so that the user can use the autocomplete again after adding one record? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering (if any), in the code behind I have a method PopulateAdditionalCost() which is called everytime a record is added or changed. I simply added the following code to the bottom of it to reload the autocomplete control

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "myscr", "LoadAuditorExtraCostsAutoComplete();", true);
```